# Can I use Ubuntu to recover Windows files?

Tags: system-installation

My very old Windows computer has a corrupted HAL DLL file and Windows will not start. I no longer have Windows disks.  I plan to download Ubuntu on another computer, burn it to a disk, and use it to start the damaged computer, thereby hopefully rescuing the files.

Will this work? Will the computer I have used to download Ubuntu be affected? Thanks so much!

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. The answers to your questions in short form: probably (but if the computer is very old I would use a lighter distro), No.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it should work! I have done it for several times, I have salvaged my desperate friend's school work, by using my Linux live USB stick to access files on their Windows PC.

So, I can speak from my own personal experience! And you don't need a CD for that. You can use an USB. Keep it safe, as an "emergency tool" for the bad days of Windows crushes.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that running Ubuntu from USB or from an optical disk (which will be slower) will let you access the Windows files.  You will just have to boot the computer with the USB (make sure your BIOS has been set to start from USB).  Once the boot screen comes up select "Try Ubuntu" (as opposed to install).  Once your system is operational, the HDD on your computer should be visible from Nautilus (the default file manager/browser in Ubuntu).  From there you will be able to browse your hard drive's contents and copy any files you need to another external USB or network drive.

If the hard drive is not visible when you start, you may need to mount the drive first.  Also note that if the original drive was partitioned, you may have to mount the different partitions to recover all your files.